# Any plan for adding API to select different temperature sensors in a nest thermostat?

Tags: nest-device-access

I noticed that there is no mention in the API for selecting sensors attached to a thermostat.  Is this limitation going to be addressed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question, but rather a request for Google to add an API.

Comment: I actually was about to post a similar question.  Although, mine was going to be asking for confirmation that the existing apis do not support reading the temp from a temperature sensor.  If someone could confirm the lack of any support for temp sensors, or point out any support that exists, I think that would be valuable.

Comment: I would also be interested if this can read temperature sensors. I don't really care as much about changing which is selected so much as wanting to read the values outside of Nest app.

Comment: I would also be interesting in it.
I just got the new nest Thermostat and it does not support the sensor :(
It's using bluetooth but I could figure out how to connect to it and use it's services.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to support temperature sensor yet. As of today, temperature sensor is not support neither by Zirconium thermostat nor GHA.